# Why sf_auth() not works for 'Environnement Sandbox Partial'?

Tags: r, salesforce, credentials

I have credentials for Salesforce API for 'production' and 'sandbox' data sets

```r
library(salesforcer)

SF_USER_NAME <- "sf_user_name"
SF_PASSWORD <- "sf_password"
SF_TOKEN <- "sf_token"

sf_auth(username = SF_USER_NAME, password = SF_PASSWORD, security_token = SF_TOKEN)
```

The code is running fine for "production" settings and fails for "Environnement Sandbox Partial" ("sandbox") settings. The most strange thing that "sandbox" settings work for Python code.

Any ideas on how to fix this bug for 'sandbox'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found at the end

```r
sf_auth(login_url = "https://test.salesforce.com/",  
        username = SF_USER_NAME, password = SF_PASSWORD, security_token = SF_TOKEN)
```

The default settings seem equal to "https://login.salesforce.com" when for for "sandbox" it should be "https://test.salesforce.com/"

Hope it will be useful as well